# React Native Maps: What's the best way to implement a draggable marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native-maps

I have a map in which I need to add a draggable marker to allow the user to pick a point.

If I choose the conventional method of

```
<MapView
initialRegion={{
....
}}>
    <Marker coordinate={this.state.coordinates} draggable />
</MapView
```

It's not a very smooth feedback for the user, since the marker first needs to be long-pressed before being draggable, and also it cannot be dragged beyond the current boundaries of the map, i.e. the user needs to manually scroll the map to a different region before being able to place the marker there.

So I found a workaround by following this concept:
https://alizahid.dev/blog/keep-marker-in-center-and-move-map-around-it

```
<MapView
initialRegion={{
latitudeDelta: 0.02,
longitudeDelta: 0.02,
latitude: this.state.coordinates.latitude,
longitude: this.state.coordinates.longitude
}}
onRegionChange={(result) => this.setState({coordinates: result})}
style={{height: 300}}
>
    <Marker coordinate={this.state.coordinates} />
</MapView>
```

This works almost perfect, except for the fact I'm using a separate function using Geolocation service to get the user's current location and place the marker there

```
componentDidMount() {
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                this.setState({
                    coordinates: {
                        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                        longitude: position.coords.longitude
                    }
                });
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
                alert("Couldn't get GPS location. Please try again or choose pickup point manually.");
            },
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 10000, timeout: 10000, showLocationDialog: true, forceRequestLocation: true})
}
```

When this function returns the location, the marker is moved to the correct point, BUT, the map does not scroll to the region where the marker is placed, since `initialRegion` does not change the region after mounting.

If I use `region` instead of `initialRegion`, the map does not scroll at all, since the `onRegionChange` callback is changing the state continuously and probably conflicting with the `region` prop.

What could be the best workaround against all the issues?

Answer (score 2):

[image]The best way is to show a marker in centre of screen by positioning it absolute.Like this

```
        <View style={styles.markerFixed}>
               <Icon
            style={{
              color: '#B11C01',
            }}
            size={30}
            name={'map-marker-alt'}
            solid
          />
        </View>

 markerFixed: {
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginTop: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '40%',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
```

Now you can drag your map to any location.Which will show effect like marker is moving.But map is moving in actual.Now use onRegionChangeComplete function to convert updated latlang to address.And you can show that converted address above the marker like in shot.

```
import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoding';
 <MapView
            style={styles.mapStyle}
              provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
              region={{
                latitude: lat,
                longitude: long,
                latitudeDelta: 0.0922 / 10,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0421 / 10,
              }}
              onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}
            />

    convertToAddress() {
        let {lat, long} = this.state;
        if (this.state.firstIndication === 0) {
          this.setState({firstIndication: 1});
          return;
        }
        Geocoder.from(lat, long)
          .then(json => {
            var addressComponent = json.results[0].address_components[0];
            this.setState({name: addressComponent.long_name});
          })
          .catch(error => console.warn(error));
      }[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The best workaround would be using [`react-native-location-view`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-location-view)

It provides you a draggable map and you can easily get the location whatever you choose by the marker.

You can refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-location-view